# How to fix Failure “INSTALL PARSE FAILED NO CERTIFICATES” for Appium & Python?

Tags: appium, appium-android, python-appium

I am making an automation script to automate a Real SMartphone Android 8.1:

**Environment**

Python 3.7
Windows 10 64Bits
Build-tools 29.0.3
java version "1.8.0_241"
Appium 1.17.1
Node v12.15.0
sdkmanager 4.0.1
ADB (Android Debug Bridge) version 1.0.41
Version 30.0.3-6597393

When I run my script, I get these error message:

```
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]
 --> We can't open Instagram. Please check if device is connected. Let's try again!
Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Performing Push Install
C:\Users\Nino\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk: 1 file pushed, 0 skipped. 87.8 MB/s (470052 bytes in 0.005s)
```

**Appium log file:**

https://github.com/gauthierbuttez/public/blob/master/appium_issue04082020.log

**What I've tried:**

I added this desired capability:
`desired_caps['remoteAppsCacheLimit'] = 0`
It didn't help.

I reset factory my Android device but it didn't help.

Does anyone already faced this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `noSign: true` to capabilities. It might help.

I also suggest manually removing Appium Settings and Instagram  apps before starting a new session.

Comment: Thank you. But I still have the issue with noSign: true. About "removing Appium Settings and Instagram apps before starting a new session.", I made a factory reset of the phone. So I think it removed everything, didn't it?